# Is the Total Differential a function or a number? Or neither.

Tags: calculus

I am reviewing multi variable calculus and am struggling with Total Differential. I read this website for my question but although there is a stock definition listed for Total Differential and how to calculate , my question is somewhat more subtle.  I assume it is not a vector not a matrix and not a number, then what kind of mathematical object is it? It seems to me to be a function of multiple variables with respect to yet ANOTHER DIFFERENT variable so that is why the chain rule is used and the output would still be a number! But online resources I am using to get the definition say it is NOT a number.  What the heck is it.  Thank you if you can shed some light!

Comment: At each point $x$ the derivative is not a number but a function.  In fact it's the linear function which best describes a small change in $f$.  That is $$f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) \approx Df_x(\Delta x),\quad \Delta x \text{ small}$$

Comment: That's not what "accepting an answer" means here.  To accept an answer you click the checkmark ✓ next to the answer you like best below.  It'll turn green and only then will that answer be said to be "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

If $f : \Omega \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, then the total differential of $f$ at a point $a \in \Omega$ is a linear map $Df(a): \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$. The Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$ is just the matrix representation of $Df(a)$ in the canonical bases of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: To take it a step further, the total differential of $f$ is a rule—i.e., a function—that assigns to each point $a$ in some subset of $\mathbb R^n$ a linear map $Df(a):\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: @amd I thought that was called the derivative map. I checked the Wikipedia article, and it uses the term "differential map at a point". Though, this is just a matter of terminology

Comment: @amd maybe the OP might clarify what exactly they mean by "total differential"

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, the terminology used for this stuff varies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is that $Df$ of $df$ has not been defined for you except for functions of one variable. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ i.e $f(\textbf{x}) = (f_1(\textbf{x}),...,f_m(\textbf{x}))$ then for $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we define $Df(a): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be the linear map such that;

$$\\$$

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(a+h) - f(a) - Df(a) \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

It turns out that actually;

$$\\$$

$$Df(a) = \left[\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} (a)\right]; 1 \leq j \leq m , 1 \leq i \leq n$$